# How to change the display for values in the fields of a form

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have a requirement like, The form has flag values, 'Private' and 'Public'. When private is selected, some of the fields(text, option set, look ups) has to be marked with '******' for display alone. Someone please help me with the code, how to change the display for the values in fields(especially optionset and lookup). The plugin is registered for retrieve and retrieve multiple on post operation.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the XRM javascript object to rename field labels.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334351.aspx)

So to change the value of a label just use:

```
Xrm.Page.getControl('new_fieldname').setLabel('New Label *');
```

You can hook into the onchange event by using

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute('new_optionset').addOnChange(function() {
    //method logic goes here
});
```